# Order of operations for solving for x

Tags: arithmetic

What is the order of operations for solving any variable? I assumed it was the opposite of PEMDAS, but in $2x^2 = 4$, you have to deal with the exponent first before dividing out to get a correct answer which breaks the order. Unlike $5^{(2x^2-1)} = 25$ which when you make the bases the same is $2x^2-1=2$. From here the answer is $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ versus $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. This confuses me. What is the correct order or are there rules etc? Also as a side question, how are logs and roots treated in PEMDAS?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151251/discussion-on-question-by-haridasa-order-of-operations-for-solving-for-x); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.